# OAuth2 Authorization Server for .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently prototyping OAuth2 authorization server options, and want to use [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4).

But it would require alot of work to put an ASP.NET Core App on top of the current .NET Framework stack (v4.5) that I am working on. This stack also relies heavily on the IoC container ["Spring"](http://springframework.net/), so thats another issue.

I have tried looking at [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server), but I run in to similar problems.

Isn't there a proper OAuth2 authorization server framework made for good old ASP.NET that is still being maintained?

Maybe some of you have some input to how you solved a similar situation?

Comment: Identity Server 3 is for .net 4.x using OAuth2.  No, it is not "current" but it is probably the best you can get.  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3

Comment: Did you see this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ ? May be can you give a better idea

Comment: Thanks both of you, yes I have seen the tutorial. And it is a road I am considering.

Comment: Hello @AndréSnedeKock - I am in your shows and wanting (now, 2 1/2 years later) to implement an authorization server for OAUTH2 in ASP.NET Framework.  Did you ever come up with a good solution?  Thanks!

Comment: @StephanG No unfortunately not, we migrated to .NET Core

Comment: Thank you - even that is useful information!